# What version of Apache Airflow includes the experimental API?

Tags: airflow

The airflow documentation states:

> Airflow exposes an experimental Rest API. It is available through the webserver. Endpoints are available at /api/experimental/. Please note that we expect the endpoint definitions to change.

https://airflow.apache.org/api.html#experimental-rest-api

However it doesn't state in which version the API appears. We are running Airflow v1.8.0

[image: airflow version info]

But whenever I browse to `/api/` or `/api/experimental/` I get a 404 and the spinning circles.

I tried curling the same URLs but that only confirmed the same, `/api/` gives me a 404:

```
$ curl -I -L -s http://${AIRFLOWIP}:8080/admin/ | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
$ curl -I -L -s http://${AIRFLOWIP}:8080/api/ | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
```

We have this setting in airflow.cfg:

```
[api]
# How to authenticate users of the API
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

I don't know whether the API is only available in a later version of Airflow or if we have stood it up incorrectly.

Can someone let me know in which version of airflow we can find the experimental API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first experimental endpoints were added in 1.8.0, with a few more endpoints added in following releases. There is no endpoint for the root paths of `/api/` and `/api/experimental/` on any version, so those curls are not expected to work. However, there is a `/api/experimental/test/` endpoint which you can hit to confirm the API is available.

If you're going to be using the experimental API, I think the [code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.1/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py) is the best reference at the moment.

Comment: fantastic, thank you Daniel. I'm using 1.8.1 in which its not `/api/test/` its actually `/api/experimental/test/` but nonetheless, yes, it works. `curl -L http://${AIRFLOWIP}:8080/api/experimental/test` returns `{"status": "OK"}`. Thank you.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you know if there's been any talk of taking it out of experimental status?

Comment: I haven't followed the status of it closely, but my guess is not anytime soon considering endpoint coverage on [master](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py) is still limited and has been untouched since June.

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow API is no more at the experimental phase.
**Stable version** here [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html).